# Extra rows with null values are being inserted in database using control file and sqlldr

Tags: oracle, csv, sql-loader

CSV is file as below:

```
C2,C3,C4
d2,d3,d4
```

Control file as below:

```
OPTIONS (DIRECT = TRUE, SKIP = 1, ERRORS=0) 
unrecoverable load data
CHARACTERSET UTF8
infile '<file name with full path>'
Append into table SCHEMA_NAME."TABLE_NAME"
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
("C1" CONSTANT 100,
"C2",
"C3",
"C4",
"C5" CONSTANT 'd5',
"C6" CONSTANT 'd6',
"C7" CONSTANT 'd7'
)
```

When I am trying to load above csv file in db using above control file and sqlldr command then extra 3 rows are inserted where columns not having CONSTANT value are null & columns having CONSTANT are filled accordingly.

Note: In db, table has all those columns which are present in control file.

I would like to avoid those extra rows insertion.

Can you please help?

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL Loader log file?  The only obvious reason for this is that your file contains additional lines with no data.

Comment: can you please explain "additional lines with no data"?

Comment: I am not getting the same issue when used your control file and given the csv file. It is loading the one record perfectly. (There is an issue with your control file syntax at ine `infile` and `C7`)

Comment: yeah, have updated that now.

Comment: @RohitKumar I mean end-of-line characters with no other data in-between.  What does `wc -l` report as the number of lines in the file?